Async workflow could not get sequential rendering
I’m trying to use Core ML model inference to render screenshots continuously. I’ve read about asynchronous prediction at WWDC, and it seems like it could improve performance. I can do it well in sync mode, but when I switch to asynchronous, things get a bit wonky.
My workflow is like this: I take a screenshot, get the copy from the screenshot, run the Core ML model asynchronously, set the RenderData, and wait for the MTKView call “draw()”. After I get the screenshot copy, I create a Task to keep the screen capture going.
Since I’m using asynchronous prediction, I need to make sure that I’m using resources in a thread-safe way. I’m using an actor RenderSemaphore to do that. But even though I update the setRenderData() function or renderAsync() that checks the frame timestamp, it still shows not sequential behavior sometimes when the refresh rate is 120 FPS (60 FPS might be okay).
I’ve attached my code below. Can you help me figure out where I went wrong? Thanks a bunch!
actor RenderSemaphore {
    private var currentBufferIndex = 0
    private var writeBufferIndex = 0
    private var frameBuffers: [FrameData?]
    private var lastReadTimeStamp: Double = 0.0
    private var lastWriteTimeStamp: Double = 0.0
    private var isRendering = false
    private var lastCommittedTimeStamp: Double = 0

    private var activeTaskCount = 0
    private let maxTasks = 3
    
    init(count: Int = 3) {
        frameBuffers = Array(repeating: nil, count: count)
    }
    
    func beginRender(timeStamp: Double) async -> Bool {
        if isRendering { return false }
        
        isRendering = true
        return true
    }
    
    func endRender() {
        isRendering = false
    }
    
    func setBuffers(surface: IOSurface, texture: MTLTexture, depth: MTLBuffer, timeStamp: Double) -> Bool {
        guard writeBufferIndex < frameBuffers.count else { return false }
        guard timeStamp > lastWriteTimeStamp else { return false }
        
        let frameData = FrameData(
            surface: surface,
            texture: texture,
            depthBuffer: depth,
            timeStamp: timeStamp
        )
        
        frameBuffers[writeBufferIndex] = frameData
        lastWriteTimeStamp = timeStamp
        writeBufferIndex = (writeBufferIndex + 1) % TotalBufferCount
        return true
    }

    func getAvailableBuffer() -> FrameData? {
        guard let frame = frameBuffers[currentBufferIndex] else { return nil }
        if frame.timeStamp > lastReadTimeStamp {
            lastReadTimeStamp = frame.timeStamp
            currentBufferIndex = (currentBufferIndex + 1) % TotalBufferCount
            return frame
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    // for setRenderDataNormalized
    func tryEnterTask() -> Bool {
        guard activeTaskCount < maxTasks else { return false }
        activeTaskCount += 1
        return true
    }
    
    func exitTask() {
        activeTaskCount -= 1
    }

    func commitFrame(timeStamp: Double,
                     commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer,
                     drawable: MTLDrawable) async -> Bool {

        guard timeStamp > lastCommittedTimeStamp else {
            print("Drop frame at commit: \(timeStamp) <= \(lastCommittedTimeStamp)")
            return false
        }
        
        commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
        lastCommittedTimeStamp = timeStamp
        
        return true
    }
}

func setRenderData(surface: IOSurface, renderData: [Float], timeStamp: Double) async {
    guard await renderSemaphore.tryEnterTask() else {
        print("drop frame")
        return
    }
    
    let result: MTLTexture!
    let _textureName = "RenderData"
    
    var px: Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>?
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithIOSurface(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                    surface,
                                                    nil,
                                                    &px)
    guard status == kCVReturnSuccess, let screenImage = px?.takeRetainedValue() else {
        await renderSemaphore.exitTask()
        return }
    
    // use texture cache
    var texture: CVMetalTexture? = nil
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(screenImage, 0)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(screenImage, 0)
    let result2 = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        self._textureCache!,
        screenImage,
        nil,
        MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm,
        width,
        height,
        0, &texture)
    
    CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(self._textureCache!, 0)
    
    if result2 == kCVReturnSuccess, let cvTexture = texture {
        let mtlTexture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(cvTexture)
        result = mtlTexture
        result?.label = "\(timeStamp)"// <--- Updated 20241118
    } else {
        await renderSemaphore.exitTask()
        return }

    let buffer = self.device.makeBuffer(bytes: renderData, length: renderData.count*MemoryLayout<Float>.stride)!
    let ret = await renderSemaphore.setBuffers(
        surface: surface,
        texture: result,
        depth: buffer,
        timeStamp: timeStamp
    )
    if !ret {
        print("drop frame")
    }
    
    await renderSemaphore.exitTask()
}

func draw(in view: MTKView) {
    Task {
        await self.renderAsync(view)
    }
}

var lastTimeStamp: Double = 0
func renderAsync(_ view: MTKView) async {
    guard await renderSemaphore.beginRender(timeStamp: frame.timeStamp) else {
        return
    }

    guard let frame = await renderSemaphore.getAvailableBuffer() else { 
        await renderSemaphore.endRender()
        return
    }

    if frame.timeStamp <= lastTimeStamp {
        print("Skipping out-of-order frame: \(frame.timeStamp) <= \(lastTimeStamp)")
        await renderSemaphore.endRender()
        return
    }
    lastTimeStamp = frame.timeStamp
    
    // Updated 20241118
    print(lastTimeStamp)
    print(frame.texture.label!)
    
    guard let commandBuffer = _commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(),
            let renderPassDescriptor = await view.currentRenderPassDescriptor,
            let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) else {
        await renderSemaphore.endRender()
        return
    }
    renderEncoder.label = "new render encoder"
    
    let (modelMatrix, leftView, rightView, projectMatrix) = self.updateMatricesAsync()
    var (sceneConstants, modelConstants) = self.getRenderConstants(
        renderPassDescriptor: renderPassDescriptor,
        projectMatrix: projectMatrix,
        modelMatrix: modelMatrix
    )
    
    // Vertex Shader
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self._vertexBufferDepth[currentBufferIndex], offset: 0, index: 0)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBytes(&sceneConstants, length: SceneConstants.stride, index: 1)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBytes(&modelConstants, length: ModelConstants.stride, index: 2)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(frame.depthBuffer, offset: 0, index: 3)
    renderEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(samplerState, index: 0)
    
    renderEncoder.setFragmentBytes(&material, length: Material.stride, index: 1)
    renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(frame.texture, index: 0)
    
    sceneConstants.viewport = 0
    renderEncoder.setViewport(viewport)
    renderEncoder.setScissorRects(scissors)
    sceneConstants.viewMatrix = viewMatrix
    renderEncoder.setVertexBytes(&sceneConstants, length: SceneConstants.stride, index: 1)
    renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(self._renderPipelineState)
    renderEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip,
                                        indexCount: self._indexBufferDepth.length/MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size,
                                        indexType: .uint32,
                                        indexBuffer: self._indexBufferDepth,
                                        indexBufferOffset: 0)
    renderEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler() { [weak self] _ in
        self?.countFPS()
    }
    
    // commit frame in actor
    let success = await renderSemaphore.commitFrame(
        timeStamp: frame.timeStamp,
        commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
        drawable: view.currentDrawable!
    )

    await renderSemaphore.endRender()
}

I have updated the code that utilizes all the actor features, which can only be executed with a single thread.

20241118 updated
I found when rendering, the timeStamp is not matched its frame's texture label that stores its timestamp, as above code marked with "20241118 updated". I don't know why the codes as below 2 lines is not matched. They should be the same!
    print(lastTimeStamp)
    print(frame.texture.label!)

Please help me!

20241121 updated
I think the result of print() shows all frames being sorted. Even though I use a sorting method to insert the frames into the array, the result sometimes includes duplicate frames or older frames.
I suspect this happens due to one of the following reasons:
The frame's address is updated or overwritten by another frame.
The commit action is concurrent or not synchronized.
However, I believe these two issues shouldn’t occur.

MultiThreaded rendering with actor - Apple Developer Forum
Replied by Apple DTS Engineer Quinn, said that I should draw(in:) frames with sync.
I can't get how to sync get the data that have to access using async before, and the Apple Engineer Quinn answered it. I think everyone here can have a look that Quinn replied.
But I'll still give the bounty to Ostoura. Thank you for your answer.

I;m glad that you solve it in synchronous mode, I watch the DTS answer and I will edit my answer by adding their suggestion and codes.

Async might not be the best choice as for all prediction cases according to WWDC
For example if the time differences between each inputs is large then the Sync prediction API would work well.
Also you can try Batch Prediction API if your input is available in batches.
Only when you have a large amount of inputs available separately in different times or individually over time then the Async Prediction API would be good.
As far as I can see you have a large time between each screenshot which makes the Sync Prediction API a good choice for you.

Update:
As I check the reply from @timyau, I have added the example from what Apple Engineer have replied.
The method draw(in:) is in fact a synchronous function and accordingly it could never be controlled except by the OS, so you have limited control over how its scheduled, Also the framework drawing methods always complete their work before returning. which is impossible to do when you bounce out to an async function.
That's why returning back to synchronous mode is the best choice for you, and the easiest way to do so is by using some sort of lock.
Here is an example:
final class SurfaceBuffer: Sendable {

    let surfaces = Mutex<[Surface]>([])

    func produce(surface: Surface) {
        self.surfaces.withLock { surfaces in
            surfaces.append(surface)
            if surfaces.count > 10 {
                surfaces.removeFirst()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func consume() -> Surface? {
        self.surfaces.withLock { surfaces in
            guard let result = surfaces.first else {
                return nil
            }
            surfaces.removeFirst()
            return result
        }
    }
}

class Renderer: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {

    let surfaceBuffer = SurfaceBuffer()

    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let surface = self.surfaceBuffer.consume() else {
            return
        }
        // … render surface …
    }

    … and more …
}

And below is the Apple Engineer Notes on that Example:

I’m using the Mutex type, which requires the latest OS releases. If you need to run on earlier systems, replace that with the OSAllocatedUnfairLock type.


I’m assuming a custom Surface type that contains all the info about the frame being produced.


That type must be sendable. That’s unavoidable in this case because you need to send values between the producer and the consumer, which are in very different contexts.


The producer refuses to buffer more than 10 surfaces. That’s an arbitrary number I picked out of thin air, so you’ll want to think carefully about it.


The consumer does nothing if there’s no surfaces in the buffer. In reality, I think you’d want it to keep a hold of the last surface it drew and just redraw that. But I’m hardly a Metal expert, so I’m not to be trusted on that front.


While sync is working well, I'm looking to optimize for 120 FPS. I'm confused why the frames aren't maintaining their sequential order as expected.

Could be the hardware itself, because 120 FPS needs a higher specs, I guess if its iOS we're talking about iPhone Pro models above 12 Pro and for iPad the new  Air or iPad Pro 2nd gen. and up, Rather if its for macOS then It would be working on M1 and up better M1 Pro and up. and about the sequential order may be you could add the sync codes to the question to check .
